# Escaped itemLabel for p:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a question regarding the primefaces component p:selectBooleanCheckbox.

I have following code, which renders a simple boolean checkbox with its label.

```html
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="agb" value="#{mobiFormF000001Model.agbChecked}" itemLabel="#{msgs['agb']}">
    <f:ajax render="submit" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Now my problem is, that in the label i have an URL, which now is escaped and my label looks like this:

```
Ich bestätige, dass ich die <a href="http://www.mobi.ch/form-sicherheit-de" target="_blank">Angaben zum Datenschutz</a> gelesen habe und diese akzeptiere.
```

Is there a way to get that part rendered as link?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use `<h:outputText>` that has the escape property?

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="agb" value="#{mobiFormF000001Model.agbChecked}" >
    <f:ajax render="submit" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{msgs['agb']}" />
```

Comment: This would work, but then the text is not a label, which means i can not click it for checking the textbox. And then it is not consistent on my page.

Comment: For the consistency, it's only a matter of applying the correct style. Concerning the possibility of clicking it, my guess is that the only way is to create a composite component, but that's not an easy task, especially if you want to have the possibility for users to use `f:ajax` tag.

Comment: Yes, thats right. I would fallback to a basic h:selectBooleanCheckbox but i have the primefaces ajaxLoader on my page, that needs to use p-tags. I'll try to contact the official Forums for primefaces, maybe there is a different approach

Answer (score 0):

You can link a `p:outputLabel` to the checkbox and put any content in its body:

```html
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.value}"/>
<p:outputLabel for="@previous">
    I agree to the <a href="..." target="_blank">terms and conditions</a>
</p:outputLabel>
```